# TinyMce Inherit Background colour

Tags: tinymce

Is it possible to get the editor to inherit the background color of the div containing it and use that as the background colour of the editor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured this out.  I edited tiny_mce.js and changed the body tag with the id of "tinymce" to have a background color of transparent.  Worked great!